# NFourierTransform gives wrong result

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis, discontinuity

This is my code:

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]

duration = 30;

tau = -1000`25;
t01 = tau - duration/2;
tf1 = t01 + duration;

intensity = 2.0`25*^10 ;

omegaL = 1240/780`25;

Emax := Sqrt[8*Pi*intensity]

Eopt[t_, tau_] = 
  Emax*(HeavisideTheta[t - t01] - HeavisideTheta[t - tf1])*
   Cos[Pi*(t - (t01 + tf1)/2)/duration]^2*
   Exp[I*omegaL*(t - (t01 + tf1)/2)];
Plot[Re[Eopt[t, tau]], {t, t01, tf1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

`Eopt[t,tau]` is a pulse with center frequency `omegaL` and it starts from `t01` and end at `tf1`. I tried to get it's spectrum by `NFourierTransform`:

```
NFourierTransform[Eopt[t, tau], t, omega21, WorkingPrecision -> 10, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

Here, the `omega21` could be any value!

Then the `NFourierTransform` always gives zero! I don't know why. The spectrum of the pulse should not be zero! 
By the way, I want to ask that how does the function `FourierTransform` work inside? I find it has few options and I can't understand it's mechanism. If it can give me good result, I'd like to accept it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are passing   `tau_` as argument to your `Eopt` function,  but inside the function, there is no `tau` to be seen?

Comment: This is the test code, fow now the `tau` is fixed for simplicity. If this code works, then I will calculate results for different values of `tau`. The `tau`  is very import in the next step of my code.

Comment: `This is the test code` Ok,. In this case, all what you have to do to see the problem is to plot your function `Eopt` against `t` and you'll see it is all zero. So I do not know why you are surprised that its fourier transform is zero.

Comment: Uh, actually, the value of `Eopt[t,tau]` is complex, so we should plot it's real part, i.e. it's physical import part.

Comment: I get zero for real part and zero for complex part and zero for the magnitude.  Could you please show a plot of `Eopt[t]` showing it is not zero including code you used to plot it?

Comment: If we change the oscillating part `Exp[I*omegaL*(t - (t01 + tf1)/2)]` into `Cos[omegaL*(t - (t01 + tf1)/2)]`, the result of `NFourierTransform` is still zero.

Comment: I've edited the problem to show the plot of `Eopt[t,tau]`. Sorry to forget that. :)

Comment: I see now. I was plotting it for different time range, that is why I get zero.

Comment: Also, please do not use `UpperCaseFirstLetter`. For example, `Duration` is Mathematica command, and you can't assign to it. You should get an error if you run your code as written.

Comment: I forget this! I use mathematica 10.4 and there is no error, maybe it is version-dependent. I've change my code and run it, the result doesn't change.

Comment: Another problem. `NFourierTransform` wants a numerical value (not symbolic) for the frequency, which you call `omega21` but you have not provided any numerical value in your code for this. So I do not know how you got zero. It should not have even done anything.

Comment: !, this code is a simplicity of my original code. the `omega21` is a value, I forgot to replace it. The `NFourierTransform` gives zero for any value of `omega21`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `HeavisideTheta` that causes trouble. As mentioned in the **Possible Issues** of its document:

> Numerical routines can have problems with discontinuous functions.

After replacing `HeavisideTheta` with `UnitStep`, the numeric transform works well:

```
NFourierTransform[Eopt[t, tau] /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep, t, -1]

(* -21288.1 - 31300.4 I *)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: @Bettertomo Thanks for accepting. Actually you don't need to accept so fast, you can wait for 24 hours or even longer to see if someone will come up with a better answer. :)

Comment: Once more, with feeling: "use `HeavisideTheta[]` for symbolic work, and `UnitStep[]` for numerical work". (@Bettertomo)

Comment: @J. M. Thanks! I'll remember it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extraneous tau value in the function definition. Then use FourierTransform to get a symbolic answer, and then plot. With the constants as defined by the OP:

```
Eopt[t_] = 
  Emax*(HeavisideTheta[t - t01] - HeavisideTheta[t - tf1])*
   Cos[Pi*(t - (t01 + tf1)/2)/duration]^2*
   Exp[I*omegaL*(t - (t01 + tf1)/2)];

ft[w_] = FourierTransform[Eopt[t], t, w]

Plot[Re[ft[w]], {w, -3, 0}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

For comparison with xzczd's answer:

```
ft[-1]
-21288.1043 - 31300.4139 I
```

Comment: I've tried `FourierTransform`, it even works if I keeps the parameter `tau` of `Eopt`. But `FourierTransform` gives out a function that seems to be a superposition of  trigonometric function with coefficient expressed by series of `w`, i.e. the variable in spectra domain. I don't know the precision of this approximation, so I hesitate to use it.

Comment: @Bettertomo `FourierTransform` finds the analytic solution for Fourier transform i.e. it's not making any approximation. You might encounter [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbugs%5Dfouriertransform) though.